# How do I reset the tags in the ranger file browser?

Tags: ranger, tagging

I have made a small script to list all my tagged files with ranger with
`ranger --list-tagged-files=*`
and put that list into another file (called todo). After a while I deleted and changed the name of some of the folders that still contained some tagged files.
Then, when I ran ranger again, I saw that all my tags were gone and I had to re-tag them.

Now, when I run my script, not only my currently tagged files are shown, but also the files that resided in the old folders that are potentially not accessible to me anymore.

Now, I would like to know how I can reset the tags in ranger, so that I can re-tag my new files again, but only see those in my todo-file.

I've checked the man page, but I could only find some `untag` and `unmark` commands that I cannot use on files and diretories that I can't access anymore.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to add my answer that I found along the way.

In the home directory, go to /.local/share/ranger

There are 3 files: *booksmarks*, *history* and *tagged*.
Just open the *tagged*-file (which is an ASCII-textfile) with a texteditor, change the respective lines, save and exit.

After listing all the tagged files with the command above (in the question), everything should be fine.